# R CMD check Warning: "Undefined global functions or variables"

Tags: r, package, namespaces, roxygen2

I am hopeful I can get advise on proper R packaging techniques. When I run `R CMD check packagename` I get these messages in reference to my zzz.R file:

```
File ‘packagename/R/zzz.R’:
  .onLoad calls:
    packageStartupMessage("my message.")
    packageStartupMessage("another message.")
    packageStartupMessage("and another message)

See section ‘Good practice’ in '?.onAttach'.

.onLoad: no visible global function definition for ‘unzip’
.onLoad: no visible global function definition for ‘file.move’
Undefined global functions or variables:
  file.move unzip
Consider adding
  importFrom("utils", "unzip")
to your NAMESPACE file.
```

I'm not entirely clear on what this means.

Per the first message, `See section ‘Good practice’ in '?.onAttach'.` I don't have an `.onAttach()` function. I just have an `.onLoad()` function. My package works fine without `.onAttach()`, so I am not sure what is being implied here.

I am not sure why I am shown `.onLoad: no visible global function definition for ‘unzip’` and `.onLoad: no visible global function definition for ‘file.move’` because I use unzip and file.move like this: `utils::unzip()`, `ff::file.move()`.

How would I add `importFrom("utils", "unzip")` to my NAMESPACE file? I have not firsthand edited this file because when I open it I get a warning not to edit it by hand.

This is what my zzz.R file looks like:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {

  quiet <- function(x) {
    sink(tempfile())
    on.exit(sink())
    invisible(force(x))
  }

  path <- paste0(.libPaths(), "/packagename/")[1]
  if(file.exists(paste0(path, "data/"))) { invisible()
    } else {
      url <- "urlpath"
      fname <- paste0(path, "data.zip")
      packageStartupMessage("message.")

      tryCatch({
        utils::download.file(url, fname, mode = "wb")

        zip_file <- paste0(path, "data.zip")
        utils::unzip(zip_file, exdir = paste0(path, "uncompressed_data"))

        from <- paste0(path, "uncompressed_data/data/")
        to <- paste0(path, "data/")

        quiet(ff::file.move(from, to))
        quiet(file.remove(paste0(path, "data.zip")))
        quiet(file.remove(paste0(path, "uncompressed_data"))) },

        warning = function(cond) {
          packageStartupMessage("message.")
          packageStartupMessage("message") } )

      }

  }
```

My NAMESPACE file just says this:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
```

Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: What exactly does your `onLoad` function look like? Are you using roxygen for documentation? Or how is your NAMESPACE file being created?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I am using roxygen, but I don't have a .Rd file for zzz.R because I did not annotate zzz.R. I just edited my question to show what my `.onLoad` function looks like and my NAMESPACE file. I am essentially using `.onLoad` to download some data.